# Unable to switch my laptop's display to an external monitor

Tags: windows, vga, external-display, hp-laptop

I have an HP G60 laptop. It's about 8 years old. Last year, the CCFL tube or inverter failed (I would see a black spot appear on the bottom right corner of the screen, which felt very hot, and eventually the screen would go black). Not long after that, it would only stay on for a few seconds before the screen went black, but the computer would remain on. This is the state that the laptop remains in as of now.

In the past, I've successfully plugged an external monitor into the laptops VGA port and transferred display to the other screen. This was about a year ago. Now, I'm attempting to do it again with a different monitor, but it doesn't work. I plug the monitor into my laptop (using my VGA cable), and then I press the fn + F4 key, which is the shortcut to switch the display on this laptop, but nothing happens. The external monitor's indicator light simply blinks, meaning it detects no output I suppose.

Both the VGA cable and the monitor are fine. I know because they were both connected to another computer as early as a month ago. Also, the monitor claims to be receiving the signal from my laptop when it's connected, it just doesn't detect any output on the screen. How should I proceed with troubleshooting this?

Comment: Does the screen have multiple inputs? You might have to select the VGA option out of the settings. Can you [edit] your question to include the make and model of your external screen?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that your monitor is claiming to receive signal from your laptop I would try to these methods just to make SURE you make the most of troubleshooting.

Try to hold WINDOWS KEY + P KEY to get windows to switch to another monitor. Also, try to press ENTER after you do so... just in case.

On method that I have found I needed to do in the past is unplug the VGA cable from your computer and then turn off your computer. With the cable still unplugged, turn the laptop back on and as its in the duration of the bios screen quickly plug the cable back into your laptop. This might catch the first signal that windows gives the monitor. It might take a few tries but use your judgement by trial and error to get the right timing. Alternativley, you can quickly unplug and plugin the VGA as it boots.

I hope these couple methods workout for you as I thought I would just suggest some tips for you to maybe fix your issue.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for those pointers, Chris. I tried both suggestions and unfortunately the result was exactly the same. Black screen on both screens, the external monitor power light flashing. I attempted to time plugging the VGA cable in a few different times, but it didn't seem to work.